# Constraints not being applied to my TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Here I have code which adds a few elements to a ConstraintLayout programmatically

```
 public void AddCategory(final String label, String img){
        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        //Create a new constraint layout
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = new ConstraintLayout(getContext());
        servicesLayout.addView(constraintLayout);
        constraintLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());
        android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams(android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.spec(android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f), android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.spec(android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f));
        layoutParams.width = 0;
        layoutParams.height = (int) scale * 200;
        layoutParams.setMargins((int) scale * 15,(int) scale * 15,(int) scale * 15,(int) scale * 15);
        constraintLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

        //Place ImageView in layout
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        constraintLayout.addView(imageView);
        imageView.setId(View.generateViewId());
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
        constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);
        constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
        if (getContext() != null){
            GlideApp.with(this)
                    .load(img)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                    .placeholder(R.color.colorGray)
                    .error(R.drawable.title)
                    .into(imageView);
        }

        //Place label background
        ImageView captionImageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        constraintLayout.addView(captionImageView);
        captionImageView.setId(View.generateViewId());
        ConstraintSet captionConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        captionConstraintSet.connect(captionImageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        captionConstraintSet.connect(captionImageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);
        captionConstraintSet.connect(captionImageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
        captionConstraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
        captionImageView.getLayoutParams().width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT;
        captionImageView.getLayoutParams().height  = (int) scale * 50;
        captionImageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        captionImageView.setAlpha(0.7f);

        //Place text in front of the label backgroudn
        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
        constraintLayout.addView(textView);
        textView.setId(View.generateViewId());
        ConstraintSet labelConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        labelConstraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, captionImageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        labelConstraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, captionImageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);
        labelConstraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, captionImageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
        labelConstraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
        textView.getLayoutParams().width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        textView.getLayoutParams().height  = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
        textView.setText(label);
}
```

The first 3 blocks of code work just fine: Programmatically adding a ConstraintLayout and two ImageViews. The problem lies within trying to constrain the TextView element. It just simply doesn't work when trying to constrain it to one of the ImageViews which is where it needs to be. It will work when constraining it to the ConstraintLayout, but that is undesirable. Instead it will ignore all constraintSet.connect code and place it in the default top right position of the layout as shown

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the endId of constraintSet for TextView like below:-

```
ConstraintSet labelConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    labelConstraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,(int)scale*15);
    labelConstraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);
    labelConstraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
```

Comment: "It will work when constraining it to the ConstraintLayout, but that is undesirable." That code will in fact bring it to the bottom, but it's at the bottom of the layout and not centered within the transparent imageview

Comment: Its not working with constraint set to captionImageView, so I have given margin  **(int)scale*15** to bottom constraint with constraint set to ConstraintLayout. I know its a hack but its looking in center.

Comment: Correct. I've tried that. It looks center, but it's not what I wanted. Thanks though!